# TFS 2010 Required Field Upon Check-In

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template, checkin-policy

My team is using TFS 2010 Agile template, and I wanted to enforce developers to fill out Completed & Remaining hours upon check-in.

Any way to make the two fields required upon check-in or somehow work this into TFS Check-In Policy?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own check-in policy:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx

or you can modify the state transitions in the work item template when the state changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194981.aspx

If I had a way to go it would be the second way (and in fact I have done similar already at my work).